# Troubleshooting tips for clustering word2vec output with DBSCAN

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, word2vec, gensim

I'm analyzing a corpus of roughly 2M raw words. I build a model using gensim's word2vec, embed the vectors using sklearn TSNE, and cluster the vectors (from word2vec, not TSNE) using sklearn DBSCAN. The TSNE output looks about right: the layout of the words in 2D space seems to reflect their semantic meaning. There's a group of misspellings, clothes, etc.

However, I'm having trouble getting DBSCAN to output meaningful results. It seems to label almost everything in the "0" group (colored teal in the images). As I increase epsilon, the "0" group takes over everything. Here are screenshots with epsilon=10, and epsilon=12.5. With epsilon=20, almost everything is in the same group.

[image: epsilon 10]
[image: epsilon 12.5]

I would expect, for instance, the group of "clothing" words to all get clustered together (they're unclustered @ eps=10). I would also expect more on the order of 100 clusters, as opposed to 5 - 12 clusters, and to be able to control the size and number of the clusters using epsilon.

A few questions, then. Am I understanding the use of DBSCAN correctly? Is there another clustering algorithm that might be a better choice? How can I know what a good clustering algorithm for my data is?

Is it safe to assume my model is tuned pretty well, given that the TSNE looks about right?

What other techniques can I use in order to isolate the issue with clustering? How do I know if it's my word2vec model, my use of DBSCAN, or something else?

Here's the code I'm using to perform DBSCAN:

```
import sys
import gensim
import json
from optparse import OptionParser

import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

# snip option parsing

model = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load(options.file);
words = sorted(model.vocab.keys())
vectors = StandardScaler().fit_transform([model[w] for w in words])

db = DBSCAN(eps=options.epsilon).fit(vectors)
labels = db.labels_
core_indices = db.core_sample_indices_

n_clusters = len(set(labels)) - (1 if -1 in labels else 0)
print("Estimated {:d} clusters".format(n_clusters), file=sys.stderr)

output = [{'word': w, 'label': np.asscalar(l), 'isCore': i in core_indices} for i, (l, w) in enumerate(zip(labels, words))]
print(json.dumps(output))
```

Comment: How did this work out? Did you stick with DBSCAN or use K Means in the end? What occurs to me is that stop words like "the" will be conneced to everything which will not be good for DBSCAN. The way the word embeddings are generated wouls also be important, did they optimise for similarity? I'd probably go with [GloVe word embeddings](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/) as they are focused on similarity.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem and trying these solutions, posting it here hoping it could help you or someone else:

- Adapting the `min_samples` value in DBSCAN to your problem, in my case the default value, 4, was too high as some clusters could also be formed by 2 words.
- Obviously, starting from a better corpus could be the solution to your problem, if the model is badly initialized, it won't perform
- Perhaps DBSCAN is not the better choiche, I am also approaching K-Means for this problem
- Iterating the creation of the model also helped me understand better which parameters to choose:

  ```
  for eps in np.arange(0.1, 50, 0.1):
      dbscan_model = DBSCAN(eps=eps, min_samples=3, metric_params=None, algorithm="auto", leaf_size=30, p=None, n_jobs=1)
      labels = dbscan_model.fit_predict(mat_words)

      clusters = {}
      for i, w in enumerate(words_found):
          clusters[w] = labels[i]
      dbscan_clusters = sorted(clusters.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
      n_clusters = len(set(labels)) - (1 if -1 in labels else 0)
      n_noise = len([lab for lab in labels if lab == -1])
      print("EPS: ", eps, "\tClusters: ", n_clusters, "\tNoise: ", n_noise)
  ```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell from the various visualizations of word2vec, the vectors probably won't cluster well.

First of all, there is nothing in the word2vec objective that would encourage clustering. On the contrary, it optimizes words to resemble the neighbors, so nearby words will get similar vectors. That is necessary for the word substitution aim.

Secondly, based on the plots, I am not sure there are "dense" regions separated by areas of low density in there. Instead, the data usually more looks like one big blob. But when almost all the vectors are in that big blob, they will almost all be in the same cluster!

Last but not least, most words probably don't cluster. Yes, numbers will likely cluster. You'd expect verbs to cluster vs. nouns, but "to bear" and "a bear" is the same to word2vec, and so is "bar" (verb and noun) etc. - there are too many polysemies for such clusters to be well separated even if the embedding were perfect!

Your best guess is to increase minors and lower epsilon until most data is noise, and you find some remaining clusters.